# Call a function in bash script with &

Tags: bash

Recently I am learning how to write bash script. 
I noticed that in other's code, there is a line calling a function like this:

```
restartApp ${array[app]} $num &
```

I know the first two are variables that passing to the function, but I really don't understand what is the last symbol & here?

Comment: Take a look at [this link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86247/what-does-ampersand-mean-at-the-end-of-a-shell-script-line)

Answer (score 0):

If you end the line with `&` the process starts in the background. This means you can continue to use the shell and do not have to wait on the output.